# Android Firebase how to loop through EVERY key of the list

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the Firebase realtime database, I have created a list with unique key for every list items.

```
String deviceId = dbDevice.push().getKey();
dbDevice.child(deviceId).setValue(device);
```

While in the other Activity, I would like to loop through each device by key, and call the method updateLatestDistance for each particular device.

Though the results of the code below functions in a weird way.
E.g. I have 2 list item, so I'll have two distance attribute, one for each list item. While the updateLatestDistance method is called, the distance value in the particular listitem should be updated, though it results in both listItem will contains both 2 latestDistance.

```
Database dbDev= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Device");
dbDev.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    //In the onstart method
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //Read the value
            //Clear and regenerate the list so that no item is multipled.
            devices.clear();
            //Loop
            for(DataSnapshot deviceSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Device device = deviceSnapshot.getValue(Device.class);
                //Add the fetched data into the local list.
                devices.add(device);

                String checkId = deviceSnapshot.getKey();

                for(int i =0; i<devices.size(); i++){
                    //Grab the latest safety_zone's latitude for later usage.
                    DatabaseReference dbSafe_La = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Device/" +checkId+ "/SafetyZone/s_latitude");
                    dbSafe_La.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //Check if safetyZone exists.
                            //If no, a 0.0 is passed.
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                la = dataSnapshot.getValue(double.class);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                    //Grab the latest safety_zone's longtitude for later usage.
                    DatabaseReference dbSafe_Lo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Device/" +checkId+ "/SafetyZone/s_longitude");
                    dbSafe_Lo.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //Check if safetyZone exists.
                            //If no, a 0.0 is passed.
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                lo = dataSnapshot.getValue(double.class);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                updateLatestDistance(checkId, la, lo);

                ///showUpdateDidalog(device.getDeviceId(), device.getNickname());
            }

            //Create a new adapter
            DeviceListAdapter a = new DeviceListAdapter(Activity_Main.this, devices);
            listViewDevices.setAdapter(a);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is the screenshot from the Firebase console as requested.

[image]

Here is the updateLatestDistance method as requested.

```
//Function - Update the distance
    private boolean updateLatestDistance(String deviceId, double safety_la, double safety_lo){

        //Compute the latest distance between device's current location & selected safetyzone location.
        //To provide real-time distance changing
        //Firebase - Push latest distance.
        DatabaseReference dbLatest_distance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Device/" +deviceId+ "/distance");
        DatabaseReference dbLatest_extra = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Device/" +deviceId+ "/extra");

        //Check if safetyZone defined
        if(safety_la!=0.0){
            float[] new_d = new float[3];
            //Compute the distance AGAIN.*
            Location.distanceBetween( Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longtitude), safety_la, safety_lo, new_d);

            //Push the distance data to the Firebase AGAIN.*
            dbLatest_distance.setValue(new_d[0]+"m");

            //If distance < 50m, trigger the alarm on the device (Raspberrypi)
            //By Sending 'on' or 'off' to Firebase.
            if(new_d[0] < 50){
                dbLatest_extra.setValue("on");
            }else{
                dbLatest_extra.setValue("off");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Post some screenshot of your firebase console if possible

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan Firebase updated.

Comment: add code for update latest distance method

Comment: @UmarHussain Hi, I have updated the code of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all since you are using ValueEventListener, when you write inside the call the latest distance you will trigger the event multiple times, so for that consider using ChildValueEvent with that you can actually respond to the change in individual devices.

Next you don't need to read value again before computation since ValueEvent or ChildEvent is real time and as soon as data changes they will get triggered again. So you don't need to read the value of safety zone using single value event.

Currently your `updateLatestDistance(checkId, la, lo);` will also not get correct value since single value event calls are async.

My suggestion would be to:

- Initialize empty array list of devices, list view adapter in `onCreate`
- Use adapter which supports notifying data change e.g. we use Recycler Adapter with Recycler View
- Use [ChildValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) on devices node of firebase database.
- onChild Add or Remove; add or remove the item from the list. (you may need to override equals method in Device class to do it directly from array list).
- onChildChange will give you events when you update a device property in firebase.
- Now since your list of devices will be in sync to database, you can check safety zone locally and set the value of on or off. (calling update latest distance in onAdd and onChange child. Also no need to check data from db for la, it will be present in you device class)

  ```
      ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

          // A new device has been added, add it to the list
         Device device = deviceSnapshot.getValue(Device.class);
              //Add the fetched data into the local list.
         devices.add(device);
         // notify your adapter about data change
         updateLatestDistance(dataSnapshot.getKey(), device.la, device.lo);
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

          //get device from list using device id for example. set the updated to the item in device list. notify
          updateLatestDistance(dataSnapshot.getKey(), device.la, device.lo);

      }

      @Override
      public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

          // remove device from the list, notify adapter.
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
  }};
  ```

Comment: Hi Umar, thanks a lot for pointing out the bad part of my code. Though I would like to know if I used the childEventListener, where should I add the code clear() and setAdapter()? They didn't fit in the onChildAdded. :/

Comment: Yoj don't need to clear the list, just add and remove items from the list and notify your adapter about change in data. Your device list adapter is extending which adapter?

Comment: Cool! I have the things work! The childEvent works well, thanks again :D